# CloudLinux access a user to root

Tags: linux, imagemagick, cpanel, vps

How to access users to root command-line in Cloudlinux?

```
for example i installed imagemagick ( convert )
```

but I can just access to that from root

convert command just works in root user

Comment: Login as root, and run `which convert` to see where you installed ImageMagick. When you know that, hopefully you can log in as a different user and add that directory to your PATH so you can use `convert`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with following command and let me know.

```
/usr/sbin/cagefsctl --addrpm imagemagick
cagefsctl --update
```